# Why bs4 wrong interpret JSON on website schema?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I want to scrape website with schema JobPosting, like this:

https://www.jobtrans.nl/vacatures/oproep-chauffeur-1806816

I using to do this requests + bs4. I do that a few times before, but in this case I have problem with parsing JSON structure and load by json library.

My code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import json

    def get_html_return_soup(url):
        try:
            client = session.get(url, timeout=15)
            html_page = client.content
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exc - {}'.format(str(e)))
            return None
        else:
            return soup(html_page, "html.parser")
            
    url = 'https://www.jobtrans.nl/vacatures/oproep-chauffeur-1806816'
    page_soup = get_html_return_soup(url)

    # get 'JobPosting' script
    json_tag = page_soup.findAll('script', type='application/ld+json')[-1].text
    #print(json_tag)

    json_response = json.loads(json_tag)
```

I getting error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Andrzej/PycharmProjects/Praca/test_bs.py", line 71, in <module>
        json_response = json.loads(json_tag)
      File "C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 6 column 242 (char 378)
```

The problem is because bs4 "loss" most part of 'description' field in JSON.

Printing json_tag :

```
   {
            "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
            "@type" : "JobPosting",
            "title" : "Oproep chauffeur",
- Vaste contactpersonen die je graag helpen bij je vragen en opmerkingen.",
            "datePosted" : "2018-07-10",
            "baseSalary": {
              "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
              "currency": "EUR",
              "value": {
                "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                "value": 0,
                "unitText": "MONTH"
              }
            },
                            "employmentType" : "PART_TIME",
                        "hiringOrganization" : {
                "@type" : "Organization",
                "name" : "Jobtrans uitzendbureau en opleider",
                "sameAs" : "https://www.jobtrans.nl",
                "logo" : "https://www.jobtrans.nl/media/large/15875392-1223350214418087-4473338085472574645-o.jpg?x=50&amp;y=50"
            },
            "jobLocation": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "Grote kerkplein 1",
                    "addressLocality": "Zwolle",
                    "postalCode": "8025BK",
                    "addressCountry": "NL"
                }
            }
        }
```

The json from website (readed on Chrome):

```
        {
            "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
            "@type" : "JobPosting",
            "title" : "Oproep chauffeur",
            "description" : "Als oproep chauffeur rijd je graag af en toe in je vrije tijd en hou je ervan om lekker op de weg te zijn. Je hebt wekelijk contact met JobTrans of er nog een klusje vrij komt die jij kunt verrichten.&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
Het mooie van het vak als oproep chauffeur is dat je altijd weer wat nieuws staat te wachten. Het komt vanzelfsprekend regelmatig voor dat door ziekte of een extra opdracht een klus vrij komt. Dit kan van alles zijn. Zo kan het zijn dat je dat je aan lading van A naar B moet vervoeren waar je een paar uurtjes werk aan hebt. Ook kun je opgeroepen worden om 15 adressen weg te brengen waar je de hele dag wel zoet mee bent. Dit zorgt er mede voor dat je veel onder de mensen komt en klantencontact hebt. Kortom; het werk van een oproep chauffeur is erg leuk en afwisselend!&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
We bieden jou als oproep chauffeur:&lt;br /&gt;
- Een goed salaris afhankelijk van relevante werkervaring als chauffeur;&lt;br /&gt;
- Werk wat bij jou past en wanneer het jou uitkomt;&lt;br /&gt;
- Korting op alle opleidingen of cursussen die we aanbieden voor de code 95;&lt;br /&gt;
- Je krijgt bedrijfskleding van ons;&lt;br /&gt;
- Vaste contactpersonen die je graag helpen bij je vragen en opmerkingen.",
            "datePosted" : "2018-07-10",
            "baseSalary": {
              "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
              "currency": "EUR",
              "value": {
                "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                "value": 0,
                "unitText": "MONTH"
              }
            },
                            "employmentType" : "PART_TIME",
                        "hiringOrganization" : {
                "@type" : "Organization",
                "name" : "Jobtrans uitzendbureau en opleider",
                "sameAs" : "https://www.jobtrans.nl",
                "logo" : "https://www.jobtrans.nl/media/large/15875392-1223350214418087-4473338085472574645-o.jpg?x=50&amp;y=50"
            },
            "jobLocation": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "Grote kerkplein 1",
                    "addressLocality": "Zwolle",
                    "postalCode": "8025BK",
                    "addressCountry": "NL"
                }
            }
        }
```

So I think the problem is with entities like '/&gt', '&lt', 'br' etc
I solved this problem long time ago like:

1. Read clear html
2. Replace wrong entities
3. Parsing JSON tag by BS4
4. Parsing JSON by json library

But I wondering is better option. In this case the problem is on the website or I doing something wrong?
I tested all BS4 parsers from documentaion (lxml, html5lib) but the same story.

Answer (score 1):

The BeautifulSoup parser interprets the data as broken html when it encounters `&lt;br /&gt;`. There are two key points to address:

- Use parser `html5lib` instead of `html.parser`; first one is more lenient than the latter when it comes to broken html; some reference
  documentation here [Differences between
  parsers](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=parsers#differences-between-parsers).

And

- Clean-up the problematic text to prepare it for `json` format; this can be done in various ways, below is one

```py
json_tag = page_soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[-1].text.replace('&lt;br /&gt;','').replace('\n','')
```

Output sample:

```
json_response = json.loads(json_tag)
print(json.dumps(json_response,indent=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. So I tried both your options before ;). html5lib not working in this case.

Comment: Both steps are required: `return soup(html_page, "html5lib")` AND `json_tag = page_soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[-1].text.replace('&lt;br /&gt;','').replace('\n','')`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want create new post, because I have similar problem with other JSON.

JSON from website -

```
https://verbund.edeka/karriere/stellenbörse/stelle-verkäuferin-feinkost-m-w-d-edeka-lüders-burgwedel-selbstständiger-einzelhandel?id=60118_60115&type=j
```

In JSON viewer like

```
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
```

is okay, but in python i get

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 20 (char 3556).
```

My code: (get_html_return_soup return bs4 object, testing with "html.parser" and "html5lib" also)

```
url = 'https://verbund.edeka/karriere/stellenbörse/stelle-verkäuferin-feinkost-m-w-d- 
edeka-lüders-burgwedel-selbstständiger-einzelhandel?id=60118_60115&type=j'

page_soup = get_html_return_soup(url)

json_tag_after = json_tag.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>')
json_response = json.loads(json_tag_after)

print(json_response)
```